# Failed to compile when I create a new angular project

Tags: angular, compiler-errors

I try to run 'ng serve' or 'npm start' in a new project and I get the following error

```
Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |  Raw Size
vendor.js             | vendor        |   1.50 MB |
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 333.14 kB |
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 230.44 kB |
main.js               | main          |  48.91 kB |
runtime.js            | runtime       |   6.51 kB |

                      | Initial Total |   2.11 MB

Build at: 2023-07-06T12:46:24.701Z - Hash: 5f2521e126e4afb7 - Time: 6963ms

./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\Nico\Desktop\Angular\test\node_modules\@angular\common\fesm2022\common.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2022/platform-browser.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\Nico\Desktop\Angular\test\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\fesm2022\platform-browser.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2022/router.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\Nico\Desktop\Angular\test\node_modules\@angular\router\fesm2022\router.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBQII.jpg)

Clarifications:

1- The error does not happen in old projects

2- Updated node.js and angular cli

3- I did not touch the code of the new project

I removed node-modules and downloaded it again but it didn't work